# VSCode で一部が文字化けする

Tags: java, windows, vscode, 文字化け

下のnameを日本語で出力すると文字化けします
文字コードをUTF-8にしても違う文字化けになるだけです
どうすればいいですか
エラーメッセージは表示されません

拡張機能はExtension Pack for JavaとJapanese Language Pack for Visual Studioです

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testtest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("あなたの名前を入力してください");
        String name = scanner .nextLine();
        System.out.println("あなたの年齢を入力してください");
        int age = scanner .nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println("ようこそ、" + age + "歳の" + name + "さん");
    }
}
```

結果
デフォルトの場合
あなたの名前を入力してください
あいうえお菊葬has
あなたの年齢を入力してください
68
ようこそ、68歳の???????????e??hasさん

UTF-8の場合
あなたの名前を入力してください
あいうえお菊葬has
あなたの年齢を入力してください
68
ようこそ、68歳の�������hasさん

Comment: javaのソースコード・コンパイル時・実行時のそれぞれのエンコーディングの指定が統一されていないのが問題なのでは？ こちらの記事 [Javaのエンコーディング指定方法](https://codeaid.jp/java-encoding/) の最後の注意とか、こちらの記事 [日本語を表示するJavaプログラムをコンパイルする時の注意について](https://qiita.com/miku0129/items/25952fd8baffb4356677) が関連していそうです。他にはこんな記事が参考になるかも。[Javaコンパイル・実行時の文字化け対策（windows10）](https://qiita.com/Friskseed/items/c02da46f7f79d9067184), [JavaのUnicode入出力問題を回避する](https://blogs.osdn.jp/2020/05/20/java-unicode.html), [java c コマンド等のjavaコンパイラが文字化けする原因が知りたい。](https://teratail.com/questions/320821)

Comment: まずは、今使っているJavaのバージョンを確認してください。（「java -version」）
多分、コマンドプロンプトの文字コードとJava VMが標準入出力に対して設定している文字コードが食い違っているのが原因だと思われます。可能なら別のバージョンのJava（たとえばjdk11とかjdk8）に切り替えても同じことが起こるかを確認してください。またVScodeのターミナルから実行しているのであればコマンド「chcp 65001」「chcp 932」を実行して結果が変わるかを確認してください。